# How can I capture webpage screenshots with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to take a screenshot of the webpage so that it can be used to share on various social media platforms. The webpage has visual elements displayed in iframe which are from different domain (not same origin).

So far i have checked

1. `html2canvas`, but looks like there is a limitation where the screenshot wolud not be generated properly if there are visual elements on the page loaded from different origin
2. `getUserMedia`: but looks like this triggers a user image capture and not webpage capture. here is link to codepen i found `https://codepen.io/jgalazm/pen/bGEgEGW`

Here are couple of my questions:

1. Is my understanding correct that `getUserMedia` cannot be used to capture webpage screenshot?
2. What other alternatives i can use to capture the webpage screenshot?

Thanks.

Comment: I think `getUserMedia` is for accessing the webcam and microphone, not taking screenshots. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia

Comment: What do “embedded links pointing to other domains”, have to do with taking a _screenshot_? Are you not actually talking about _links_, but embedded _media_ from other origins, or what exactly? Or 3rd-party content displayed in (i)frames, that you want to be included in those screenshots?

Comment: @CBroe the links on page that i need to take screenshot has visual elements loaded using iframe from a different domain. there is limitation mentioned in `html2canvas` https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation hence thought it might be important to specify

Comment: @CBroe have updated my question for more clarity, hope it helps. Thanks.

Comment: Under those circumstances, I don’t think there is anything that will work directly within your page’s context, and directly in the user’s browser. This would likely need elevated access that only a browser extension can provide.

Comment: You wouldn't want joe.evil.example.com to be able to stick `<iframe src="your-very-private.example.com">` in a page and then be able to screenshot it (and then send a picture of your private data to Joe Evil's server with Ajax).

Comment: If those screenshots could be created elsewhere (i.e., no user-specific content on those pages), and you have enough server access, then you could perhaps implement something like this, https://24ways.org/2018/dynamic-social-sharing-images/

Comment: thanks @CBroe, i think that might be a good approach. generate a screenshot using different app (node.js) and send the image back to the requesting app which can be then shared on social media platform. The only issue i see with this is time taken to generate the screenshot image

Comment: [`getDisplayMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia)?

Comment: @MattF thanks for your reply. i am checking this now.

Answer (score 0):

what I've found best is to handle this server side.

So you use selenium with chrome / firefox / phantom js and you render and then take the screen shot through the selenium api.

selenium is primarly Java or Python

https://pythonspot.com/selenium-take-screenshot/

if javascript is more of your thing than opt for puppeteer

https://buddy.works/guides/how-take-screenshots-with-puppeteer-headless-chrome

### Deployment

If I knew more about your backend then I could answer more thoroughly.

If you are using a cloud provider, I'd recommend a serverless function.

If you have a node server than Puppeteer

If you have a python server than selenium.